# Import Windows 7 links to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I want to import Windows 7 links (so the favorites for Windows Explorer) to Windows 10 (it's called quick access there)

If I just copy paste the `C:\Users\$USERNAME\Links` to `C:\Users\$USERNAME\Links` it doesn't work in Windows 10.

No error message but the links (around 50) I copy pasted just don't show up in Quick Access, not even when I restart `explorer.exe` either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to each source drag and drop it in quick access, As far as I know that is the only solution for now.